# Excel VBA - UDF returns 0 or empty or #value

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am creating my customized function. I wrote the code and tested it as “sub and it worked well. Then i converted it into a function to be able to use it in general. Things that i changed are; adding a function declaration, taking input from excel cell and specifying function output. All others remained same.

My function only has one input which is a selected cell from an excel sheet. And i expect that function returns one output. However, it returns 0.
•   function declaration. "Function IbpBomLevel(ByVal Target As Range) As Variant
•   input of function as selected cell. "ProductID = Target
•   output of function. "IbpBomLevel = fullText

I used option explicit to avoid non-exist functionalities. Also, I am sure about the input, function really takes the selected cell as input. But the problem is that in each loop “ProductID must be changed. Hovewer, when i declared that "IbpBomLevel (output of the function) = ProductID and saw that ProductID is the first parameter that user selected from a cell. It means loop not works. When i test it as “sub, i got the result that i want. I am not sure what the problem is.

```
Option Explicit

Function IbpBomLevel(ByVal Target As Range) As Variant

Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim SourceID As Variant
Dim SourceID2 As Variant
Dim SourceID3 As Variant
Dim Product As Variant
Dim Item As Variant
Dim Location As Variant
Dim Resource As Variant
Dim I As Variant
Dim T As Variant
Dim Z As Variant
Dim X As Variant
Dim Y As Variant
Dim Index As Variant
Dim Index2 As Variant
Dim Index3 As Variant
Dim BomLevel As Variant
Dim FoundCell As Variant
Dim fullText As Variant

Dim ProductID As Variant
ProductID = Target

Set Wb = Workbooks("Kitap.xlsx")
Windows("Kitap.xlsx").Activate

On Error GoTo T_Error

Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Production Source Header")
Sheets("Production Source Header").Select

Set MyRange = Worksheets("Production Source Header").Range("B:C")

SourceID = CVar(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProductID, MyRange, 2, False))

I = 1
T = 0
Z = 1

If IsEmpty(SourceID) = False Then

    Do While (IsEmpty(SourceID) = False) And (T = 0)

        BomLevel = Z

        Windows("Kitap.xlsx").Activate
        Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Production Source Header")
        Sheets("Production Source Header").Select
        Set MyRange = Worksheets("Production Source Header").Range("B:C")

        SourceID = CVar(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProductID, MyRange, 2, False))

        Set FoundCell = ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Find(What:=SourceID)

        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            Index = FoundCell.Row
            Location = Cells(Index, 1)
            Product = Cells(Index, 2)
        Else
        End If

        X = I
        I = I + 1

        Windows("Kitap.xlsx").Activate
        Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Production Source Item")
        Sheets("Production Source Item").Select
        Set MyRange = Worksheets("Production Source Item").Range("B:B")

        SourceID2 = CVar(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SourceID, MyRange, 1, False))

        Do While (IsEmpty(SourceID2) = False) And (I - X = 1)

            Set MyRange = Worksheets("Production Source Item").Range("B:B")

            SourceID2 = CVar(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SourceID, MyRange, 1, False))

            Set FoundCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Find(What:=SourceID2)

            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                Index2 = FoundCell.Row
                Item = Cells(Index2, 1)
                Windows("Kitap.xlsx").Activate
                Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Production Source Header")
                Sheets("Production Source Header").Select
            Else
            End If

            Y = I
            I = I + 1

            Windows("Kitap.xlsx").Activate
            Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Production Source Resource")
            Sheets("Production Source Resource").Select

            Set MyRange = Worksheets("Production Source Resource").Range("B:B")

            SourceID3 = CVar(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SourceID, MyRange, 1, False))

            Do While IsEmpty(SourceID3) = False And (I - Y = 1)

                Set MyRange = Range("B:B")
                    SourceID3 = CVar(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SourceID, MyRange, 1, False))
                Set FoundCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Find(What:=SourceID3)

                If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                    Index3 = FoundCell.Row
                    Resource = Cells(Index3, 1)
                    Windows("Kitap.xlsx").Activate
                    Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets("Production Source Header")
                    Sheets("Production Source Header").Select
                Else
                End If

            I = I + 1

            Loop
        Loop

        fullText = fullText & " Location: " & Location & " // Header: " & Product & " // Item: " & Item & " // Resource: " & Resource
        Z = Z + 1

        ProductID = Item
        Set MyRange = Worksheets("Production Source Header").Range("B:C")

        SourceID = (Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ProductID, MyRange, 2, False))

T_Error:
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then

            On Error Resume Next
            T = 1

        Else
        End If

    Loop

    IbpBomLevel = fullText

Else
    MsgBox ("Bom Missing")
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Since this is a UDF, all workbook, worksheet and range reference should be derived from input parameters to the Function.  Also all Activates and Selects must be eliminated

Comment: It's not clear to me what result you wanted and what you are getting.  I would try putting a breakpoint in the function single-stepping through the code, and watching the values of I, T, X and Z.Many things could be improved.  Some to look at include: using more descriptive variable names; avoiding `activate` or `select`; not declaring everything as `Variant`.